# jquery plugins mirror

Tags: jquery

I'm mostly link my scripts to external sites, like ajax.googleapis.com and view.jquery.com.

Today, all of a sudden, the URL http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js is not available anymore. I should have made a copy.

Problem is, is that my autocompletion is not working anymore. Quite important with this site, because it helps people entering the proper city name.

Anyone knows a mirror site for the Jquery plugins? I got to have a new copy today, or hopefully the server comes back, as it seems that everything under /trunk is gone.

Comment: Or maybe someone can send me a copy of their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could've just google'd it....anyways you can find it here

http://plugins.jquery.com/node/2404/release?order=file_name&sort=asc

Comment: I was on that page earlier and it was empty. Thank you anyway :)